# How to embed a shiny application into an Rmarkdown html document

Tags: html, r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I would like to create an html document with RMarkdown, containing text, Rcode and somewhere in between a shiny application.

- I thought of using `asis=TRUE` for the `shinyApp(ui, server)` block, but RStudio only renders the Rmd file, if I add `runtime: shiny` to the YAML-Header.
- If I do so, no html is created, but I can move to browser view.
- If I look at the source code in the browser view , I still don't see the entire html code.
- If I check the generated temporary file, I was not able to find the html file representing the entire RMarkdown document.

How to generate html-code from the shinyApp function?
Or: How to generate an html file, from RMarkdown containing a shiny app instead of e.g. a plot

I hope you have some idea for me.

Comment: [link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html)  Read the comments section

Comment: @aRise I am currently using the Inline approach, but either get the shiny app working without html, or the html working, without the shiny app. I think I may have some misunderstanding here. May you show me the way?

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand what you mean by "a shiny application". If you have already set up a server side application, i.e. others can assess your application via url, you can try the following approach.

see https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/web-pages-and-shiny-apps.html, second paragraph

> A related function is `knitr::include_app()`, which is very similar to `include_url()`, and it was designed for embedding Shiny apps via their URLs in the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I still don't get it. May you give me an example? Do I need to add a codeblock containing the `ui` and `server` component? Do I need to call the function `shinyApp(ui,server)` before? Do I need to put the shiny code in a different folder / project or the very same markdown file? Where do I get the URL from?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then maybe the following URL could be of help for you:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-start.html

As you can see: You don't have to follow the Shiny skeleton template. The only thing to do: You have to add the line `runtime: shiny` into the YAML-header and publish the `.Rmd` file in the normal way, e.g. you have to include a standard r code snippet in your RMarkdown document where you can write your shiny code.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

'Note: If you are familiar with R Markdown, you might expect RStudio to save an HTML version of an interactive document in your working directory. However, this only works with static HTML documents. Each interactive document must be served by a computer that manages the document. As a result, interactive documents cannot be shared as a standalone HTML file.'

https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/interactive-docs/